# Create by hand a formatted form of quantities

Tags: formatting, units

If I evaluate the following cell:

```
Quantity["PlanckConstant"]
```

I get as an output a very concise format of this quantity:

[image]

Also, compare the legibility of these two cells:

[image]

I want to find a way to create this:

[image]

without first evaluating a cell.

I just assume that the notebook front-end allows the user to achieve such a thing: just as right clicking on `Sqrt[2]` and clicking on Convert To -> StandrdForm converts this expression to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: `Style["h", Italic]` ?

Comment: Nope. `Style["h", Italic]` is not a `Quantity`.

Comment: if you mean you want to type that slanted h and have evaluate to `Quantity["PlanckConstant"]` without doing anything, then I do not know how to do that. May be someone else will have an idea. This seems to be builtin the notebook interface itself. Will delete my answer in this case.

Comment: If I understand correctly: Select your `Quantity[...]`, then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter (or go to the menu Evaluation > Evaluate in place). This will evaluate just the selected expression and not the whole cell :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do evaluation in place, which can be achieved either by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or in the menu `Evaluation > Evaluate in Place`.

[image]

Comment: By the way, are you using any shortcut to delete the parentheses? I know the `CTRL` with `^` shortcut to create parentheses around the selection. But not a shortcut to delete them.

Comment: Uhm, no, just the plain old Backspace and Delete :)